# EF6 Set DateTime to Null on Update

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

You may think this is same question as other around but I've checked and can't find an answer, so please if anyone could help...

I have this class which has many other properties, but let's focus in this 2...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Both EndDate and State has some values in Database.
Ex. EndDate = 2016-11-20 00:00:00 and State = "Closed".

What I need is to Change those values, so I have an Action button which does this...

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
{
    MyClass rec = new MyClass { Id = Id };
    db.MyClasses.Attach(rec);
    rec.State = "Opened";
    rec.EndDate = null;
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
}
```

But, when I run this command, the State is changed in Database to "Opened" but the EndDate stills same value as before, I mean it does not turn NULL.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't actually change the end date:

```
MyClass rec = new MyClass { Id = Id };
db.MyClasses.Attach(rec);
...
rec.EndDate = null;
```

But it was `null` when you attached the entity.

So you have to tell the change tracker that the property is modified:

```
db.Entry(rec).Property(r => r.EndDate).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: Well that did the job. With a slight change... db.Entry(rec).Property(r => r.EndDate).IsModified = true; Thanks.

Comment: but then how `rec.State` changed without an issue ?

Comment: @Sampath `rec.State` is probably `null` when `rec` is initialized.

Comment: yes,but OP mentioned that value has been updated correctly no ? I mean without `.IsModified = true` on `State` property ?

Comment: Sure, in that case the change tracker notices the change `null` => "Opened". `EndDate`, however, is set to `null` while it already is `null`.

Comment: Great ...Thanks for the clarification +1 :)

Comment: State is never NULL... I mean, never NULL before hit the Action Button. However, before this change in the code, there was no issue! Only the Property State changed. EndDate couldn't change to NULL.